# Understanding and Resolving Concurrent Modification Exception in Java Collections

Tags: arrays, string, sorting, merge, public

I'm exploring Java programming and have encountered a situation where I need to efficiently handle concurrent operations. Could you please share insights or best practices for managing concurrency in Java? I'm particularly interested in recommended classes, strategies, or patterns that the community finds effective. Thank you! please help me